# ios https incommunicado: Installing PEM certificate

Tags: ios, keychain

I have a test website that ios can't communicate to cause certificate is predictably trash.
I have clicked on lock icon in browser url and have extracted pem chain of cerificates
for that site.

How could I install it into keychain on macos simulator or ios device to
have that https connection trusted? (for testing purposes)

When attempting to drag and drop pem into simulator window:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AirDrop profiles and certificates to iOS works in general.

If the file you send isn’t accepted you might have to [prepare a proper configuration profile and sign that](https://support.apple.com/guide/profile-manager/create-and-edit-configuration-profiles-pmd8571919q/mac) to embed arbitrary unsigned or self-signed certs.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209435

Comment: it's rw-rw-rw- and. yet. macos complains abvout permissions when I drag and drop it into simulator. How do I prepare a proper configuration profile?

Comment: This works on iOS devices. @AntonTropashko I answered the part of “simulator or device” - not sure this works for “simulator and device”

Comment: So far can't get cataline 10 15 6 to see my ios 12.4.6 phone. will try from another computer i suppose in half a day. Thanks!

Comment: OK - If AirDrop isn’t working, you’ll have some other things to sort for sure before you can continue developing or testing with confidence. Good luck!